# Sails.js Access Model on Service initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

### The question:

As I understand in **sails.js** during initialization process Services are initialized before Models.

Is there any possibility to change this behavior? To make Models load before Services.

If it's not, then how can I load particular settings from the database to use them to build instance of my class described in some Service during this Service initialization?

### A little bit code for solidity:

#### api/models/Model.js

```
console.log("Model Identified");

module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: { type: 'string', required: true, size: 15 },
        //Some extra secret fields
    }
};
```

...

#### api/services/MyCoolService.js

```
console.log('service inits');

function MyCoolService(options){
    //some extraordinary constructor logic may be ommited
}

MyCoolService.prototype.setOptions = function(options){
    //Set values for MyCoolService fields.
}

//Some other methods

var myCoolServiceWithSettingsFromDb = new MyCoolService();

//That's the place
model.findOne(sails.config.myApplication.settingsId).exec(function(err,result){
    if(!err)
        myCoolServiceWithSettingsFromDb.setOptions(result);
});

module.exports = myCoolServiceWithSettingsFromDb;
```

Comment: Can you give more specific description or code? Because `models` are accessible from the services.

Comment: During initialization sails initializes services first.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you instantiate object in service with constructor that needs `sails` that not exist. Try use this at `MyCoolService`;

```
module.exports = {
  someOption: null,
  method: function () {
    var that = this;
    sails.models.model.findOne(sails.config.myApplication.settingsId)
      .exec(function (err, result) {
        if (!err)
          that.someOption = result;
      });
  }
};
```

that method can be called by `sails.services.mycoolservice.method()` or simply `MyCoolService.method()` to give your service some option from DB.

If you want to initiate them at Sails start, call that method at `config/bootstrap.js`

Comment: If you still want to use constructor function, call that constructor from `config/bootstrap.js` to make sure `sails` is exist/ lifted. Because it doesn't matter what hooks is loaded first, if you want to use `sails` hooks, Sails it self must be loaded, and the good approach is use it's built in `bootstrap`.

Comment: Thanks. Thats a good approach. But say I want to get instance of MyCoolService set by settings from Model to be avaliable all over the controllers later. What should I do then?

Comment: Wait, what did you want to look after? Is it `sails.models` object that already built by complicated sails orm, or just `Model` configuration settings, like it's attributes, one of it's enums, etc.?

It would be very difficult if you want complete `sails.models` that has been built by ORM, but if it just Model's configuration, it can be done pretty easy.

Comment: I want my instance of MyCoolService which is created using just data from Model to be avaliable for all the controllers and services over the application. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Andi Nugroho Dirgantara**,
I ended up with this solution (I still don't like it much, but it works):

#### api/services/MyCoolService.js

```
console.log('service inits');

function MyCoolService(options){
    //some extraordinary constructor logic may be ommited
}

//All the same as in question

//The instance
var instance;

module.exports = module.exports = {
    init: function(options) {
        instance = new MyCoolService(options);
    },
    get: function() {
        return instance;
    },
    constructor: MyCoolService
};
```

#### config/bootstrap.js

```
...
Model.findOrCreate({ id: 1 }, sails.config.someDefaultSettings).exec(function(err, result) {
    if (err)
        return sails.log.error(err);
    result = result || sails.config.someDefaultSettings;
    MyCoolService.init(result);
    return sails.log.verbose("MyCoolService Created: ", TbcPaymentProcessorService.get());
});
...
```

#### tests/unit/service/MyCoolService.test.js

```
...
describe('MyCoolService', function() {

    it('check MyCoolService', function(done) {
        assert.notDeepEqual(MyCoolService.get(), sails.config.someDefaultSettings);
        done();
    });

});
...
```

It works: the service is instantiated once while bootstraping and it's instance is avaliable everywhere.

But to me this solution still weird... I still don't understand how to globally instantiate instance of my service (for use in a lot of controllers) and make it the best way.

Comment: It's weird because you use classic OOP pattern at Javascript, same as with Sails. But as long as it's works, no problems then :D

Comment: Maybe... I came here from Java World. Oh I miss Spring's IoC so much!